# How to use mathptmx and txfonts combined?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am a new LaTeX user. After a long search, I realized that the best fonts for my work are `txfonts` and `mathptmx`. However, I wish I could use both fonts combined. For example, using the font `mathptmx` as a primary font and use some elements of `txfonts`, as the symbol for the integral. Is this possible?

In the preamble, used the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

This preamble allows me to use `mathptmx` as math font. I can also use some elements of `txfonts` without any special configuration such as the command `\varmathbb{R}`.

But I can not replace the symbol of the integral of `mathptmx` by `txfonts` symbol...

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fonts of the `mathptmx` and `txfonts` packages are both derived from Times Roman. If you prefer the text fonts of the latter package but like the math fonts of the former package, you can type

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

in the preamble. The second instruction tells LaTeX to load the `ptm` text font. (For comparison, the corresponding instruction in the `txfonts` package is `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{txr}`.) This way, you'll also get access to the monospaced fonts that come with the `txfonts` package; I personally find them very pleasing (as well as compatible with Times-like roman fonts).

How to go about retaining certain parts of the math-fonts part of the `mathptmx` package is not really possible to determine because you don't provide an explicit list of *which* parts of the `mathptmx` package you prefer over those provided by the `txfonts` package. The former package provides the following mathfont-related instructions:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bold}        {OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}      {OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\@ifundefined{mathbf}{}{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}}
\@ifundefined{mathit}{}{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omicron}{0}{operators}{`\o}
```

whereas the latter package sets:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators}
\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{italic}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{txmi}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathfrak}{lettersA}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
```

I trust it won't be too hard to figure out how to mix-and-match the various combinations.

Comment: Thank you. However, not is the fonts of the text body that I looking for.

There are elements I like best in mathptmx as the design of the radicals and the parentheses, and others that I prefer the txfonts, as the drawing of the symbol of the integral ...

That is, the doubt is only in math mode: how to select certain styles of two or more packages.

Comment: `times.sty` is obsolete as it loads Helvetica as the sans serif font without scaling it appropriately. To set only the text font to Times, [`psnfss2e.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf#subsection.9.1) suggests using the basic NFSS command `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`.

Comment: @diabonas -- good point about the `times` package setting the sans-serif font to `Helvetica` (and the monospaced font to `Courier`) without regularizing the font sizes to achieve even a semblance of compatibility between Times, Helvetica, and Courier. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for editing your initial answer! That's what I was looking for! I think with a little study I can make the changes I need.