# Use (normal) \varpi and txfonts \varpiup without change the whole article to txfonts

Tags: txfonts

I want to use `\varpi` in normal font and `\varpiup` from `txfonts`.
I don't want to change the font for general text.

I have read quickly the following answers, but I don't understand
and don't know how  to use them for my purpose.

A further question arise : How if I want to use the two different `\varpi` both
in normal font and in `txfonts`? I guess I need to create a new command like `\varpitxfonts`?

In general, how to use, in the same time, some characters or symbols that have the same names in more than one fonts?

[How to use mathptmx and txfonts combined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47550/how-to-use-mathptmx-and-txfonts-combined)

[Text affected by using txfonts package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70040/text-affected-by-using-txfonts-package)

Comment: What is your "normal" font?

Comment: this might be helpful: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some wandering inside `txfonts.sty` allows us to distill the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpitx}{\mathord}{TXlettersA}{36}

\begin{document}

This is \verb|\varpi|: $\varpi$

This is \verb|\varpitx|: $\varpitx$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure you want to use both symbols in one and the same document? I wouldn't be and I'm pretty sure your readers will appreciate if you don't.

Comment: Thank you. Why not to use both of them in the same document? They are different enough to distinguish. In fact, I used \varpi and \boldsymbol{\varpi}, and I was told that it is difficult to distinguish. This is why I want to use \varpiup rather than \boldsymbol{\varpi}.